# Setting S3 to post notifications to SQS when new item is created

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I am trying to do (what should be) a simple task.

- Create an S3 Bucket
- Create an SQS Queue
- Have the S3 bucket put a message in the SQS Queue whenever a new item is added.

I am getting stuck on attaching the two.

I've created the queue, and it works well.  I've created the bucket, and it works well.

Now i'm trying to add a policy to the queue that will let the bucket send notifications.

Following this guide:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ways-to-add-notification-config-to-bucket.html

I am trying to call this method:

```
  public SetQueueAttributesResponse SetQueueAttributes(Dictionary<string, string> attributes)
    {
        var setQueueAttributesRequest = new SetQueueAttributesRequest()
        {
            QueueUrl = QueueUri.ToString(),
            Attributes = attributes
        };

        return SqsClient.SetQueueAttributes(setQueueAttributesRequest);
    }
```

And the attributes property has a single key/value pair:

```
Policy

{
"Version" : "7/5/2017",
"Id"      : "S3-Post",
"Statement" : [
    {
        "Sid" : "S3-Post",
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Principal" : {
            "AWS" : "*"
        },
        "Action"    : [
            "sqs:SendMessage",
            "sqs:GetQueueUrl"
        ],
        "Resource"  : "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:[REDACTED]:testqueue2",
        "Condition" : {
            "ArnLike" : {
                "aws:SourceArn" : "arn:aws:s3:*:*:*"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

(Yes, I widened the filter condition slightly, but got this same failure with a bucket name established.)

I get this exception:

> Amazon.SQS.AmazonSQSException was unhandled
>
> ErrorCode=InvalidAttributeValue
>
> HResult=-2146233088
>
> Message=Invalid value for the parameter Policy.
>
> RequestId=0ac6201a-17f5-5b63-a5ac-71cd42b10481
>
> Source=AWSSDK.Core

Can anyone see my error, or can anyone point me to a more functional example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Version` refers to the version of IAM policy language in use, not a revision of your policy.

There's only one value you want to use: `"2012-10-17"`.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Version

Comment: Gad, I missed that.  I turned it around with something else.  Change made it work first try. Thanks so much!  My coffee pot can take the night off, now!